# How much theory will change if we drop usual metric and use some different metric on $R^k$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

In $\mathbb{R}$,under usual metric, $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ but this is not true if we put discrete metric on $\mathbb{R}$.

In what amount will theory get affected if we use some different metric other than usual one? For example, when we say, $E\subset \mathbb{R}^k$, is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded, we refer to usual metric on $R^k$. But this may not hold under some different metric, so will that metric lead to a completely different theory of subject?

Thanks.

Comment: What is $R$ here?

Comment: Field of real numbers

Comment: The code for real numbers is usually `\Bbb R`.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: everything will change. If you remove the metric from $\mathbb{R}$, all you have left is an uncountable set with no structure. So you can make $\mathbb{R}$ look like an arbitrary uncountable metric space. By using a bijection $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and giving it the induced metric from $\mathbb{R}^n$ you can make $\mathbb{R}$ like $\mathbb{R}^n$, or like a separable Hilbert space, or like the uncountable discrete space as you already mentioned. These examples show that compactness very much depends on the metric and you cannot expect any Heine-Borel type result if you change the metric.

EDIT: This refers to removing the topology completely. If you only change the metric but keep the topology, the answer is much different.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the topology